# Android testing - change system value for testing logical branch

Tags: android, android-testing

I've got a method that tries to start a browser with a specific URL, or if the device does not have a browser installed, instead starts an `Activity` with a `WebView` and loads the same URL.  Basically this:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, url);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

How can I test both branches?  Is it possible to unregister the Browser activity from the device, temporarily and programmatically?

I had considered a `Shadow` `Activity` that just throws an `ActivityNotFoundException` when that particular `Intent` was passed to it (i'd check the data URI), but AFAIK there's no way to turn that `Shadow` on for one test and off for the other.

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

This is really over engineering.  The odds that the user doesn't have a web browser on the device is 0.  It isn't worth worrying about.

If you're worried about the url being invalid and unparsable, its unlikely this would fix that problem, as it would be unparsable in your web view activity as well.  If you really want to be paranoid I'd catch it and toast an error.

As for testing it-  refactor to make it testable.  Write this as a function that takes a URL as a parameter.  For the bad version, use a URL like thisisnotavalidscheme://example.com.  That will fail as nobody is going to be registered for that scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  There are actually quite a few devices in the wild without browsers; we see them daily, and this fallthrough does get used.  I'm just asking if there's a way to fool the system, or leverage and existing toolset, to mimic that state.

Comment: My guess is you're seeing invalid urls that don't start with http(s) rather than not having a browser.